# In python dataframe how to select rows based if all the columns values are same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below format of df:

```
Name  A1   A2  A3  A4
def   0    0   0   0
def1  0    1   0   0
def2  0    0   0   0
def3  1    0   0   0
def4  0    0   0   0
```

Expected output:

```
Name  A1   A2  A3  A4
def   0    0   0   0
def2  0    0   0   0
def4  0    0   0   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use if `Name` is first column compare first column by all columns selected by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:]
#if `Name` is any column
#df1 = df.drop('Name', axis=1)

df = df[df1.eq(df1.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   Name  A1  A2  A3  A4
0   def   0   0   0   0
2  def2   0   0   0   0
4  def4   0   0   0   0
```

If `Name` is index:

```
print (df)
      A1  A2  A3  A4
Name                
def    0   0   0   0
def1   0   1   0   0
def2   0   0   0   0
def3   1   0   0   0
def4   0   0   0   0


df = df[df.eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
      A1  A2  A3  A4
Name                
def    0   0   0   0
def2   0   0   0   0
def4   0   0   0   0
```

If performance is not important, because slow in large DataFrame use [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
df = df[df.nunique(axis=1).eq(1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.nunique` with `axis=1`:

```
df.set_index("Name").nunique(1).eq(1)
```

Output:

```
Name
def      True
def1    False
def2     True
def3    False
def4     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach is to check the variance of each column:

```py
df[df.var(axis=1) == 0]
```

```
Name  A1   A2  A3  A4
def   0    0   0   0
def2  0    0   0   0
def4  0    0   0   0
```

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks for pointing it out. I forgot to write `axis=1` so it was working column-wise. Try my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Using the drop method on your dataframe you delete the entire row.

```
data.drop(["def1", "def3"], inplace = False)
```

The first argument is a list of index.
Inplace argument is to change the original dataframe if true.

to learn more visit:
[Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)